# Create a variable which accepts only two values. Values being -1 and 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across a situation where in a variable should accept only two values; Values being -1 and 1. I created a rule and bind that to the a new type that I have created. But it is still accepting other values. Following is the code.

```
EXEC sp_addtype Dimension_Type, 'TINYINT', 'NOT NULL'

CREATE RULE rule_Dimension_Type AS @Dimension_Type IN (-1,1)
EXEC sp_bindrule 'rule_Dimension_Type', 'Dimension_Type'

CREATE DEFAULT def_Dimension_Type AS 1
EXEC sp_bindefault 'def_Dimension_Type', 'Dimension_Type'

DECLARE @X AS Dimension_Type
SET @X = 22
```

Comment: Better make it a bit data type and case it when 0 then -1. Instead of making rules.

Comment: Why would you be using [`CREATE RULE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx) these days? "Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."

Comment: And, of course, that same page tells you exactly why it's not working: "A rule bound to an alias data type is activated only when you try to insert a value into, or to update, a database column of the alias data type. Because **rules do not test variables**, do not assign a value to an alias data type variable that would be rejected by a rule that is bound to a column of the same data type.", my emphasis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a stored procedure which takes -1 or 1 as as input. So I thought applying rule while accepting parameters instead of Stored procedure body. Now I am handling this validation in stored procedure body.